# ModelForm __init__ problems

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've attempted to modify my Django ModelForm `__init__` constructor so that it will accept a passed variable ('admin'), look to see if `admin == True`, and if so, make a couple of fields ('applicant_affirmation' & 'applicant_interest_stmt') display as non-modifiable. The fields are being shown as non-modifiable, as desired, but the `.update()` function isn't happening because it is not getting past the `if form.is_valid` check. I've checked for `form.non_field_errors` and `form.errors`, but nothing is there. The updates work fine if the `__init__` method is commented out.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing? Admittedly I don't have a strong understanding of building a constructor yet. Help would be very much appreciated.

```
class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('program', 'status', 'applicant_affirmation', 'applicant_interest_stmt', 'applicant_school', 'applicant_major', 'applicant_school_2', 'applicant_major_2', 'gpa_univ', 'estimated_grad_semester')
        widgets = {
            'applicant_interest_stmt': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}),
            'estimated_grad_semester': Select(),
        }

    def __init__(self, admin, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if admin:
            self.fields['applicant_interest_stmt'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
            self.fields['applicant_affirmation'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'


    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        cleaned_data = super(ApplicationForm, self).clean()
        applicant_interest_stmt = cleaned_data.get('applicant_interest_stmt')
        applicant_affirmation = cleaned_data.get('applicant_affirmation')
        if not applicant_interest_stmt:
            msg = u'Please provide an interest statement.'
            self._errors["applicant_interest_stmt"] = self.error_class([msg])
        if not applicant_affirmation:
            msg = u'Please check the affirmation checkbox.'
            self._errors["applicant_affirmation"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return cleaned_data
```

Application Model:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, verbose_name="certificate program")
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, verbose_name="application status")
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    applicant_affirmation = models.BooleanField()
    applicant_interest_stmt = models.TextField(verbose_name="In a few sentences, briefly explain why you are interested in this program and what you expect to get out of it")
    applicant_school = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="school (primary)")
    applicant_major = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="major (primary)")
    applicant_school_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name="school (secondary)")
    applicant_major_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name="major (secondary)")
    gpa_univ = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="GPA (university)")
    estimated_grad_semester = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name="estimated graduation semester")
    _created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, blank=False)
    _created_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    _updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, blank=False)
    _updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        cleaned_data = super(Application, self).clean()
        if not self.applicant_affirmation:
            raise ValidationError('Please check the affirmation checkbox.')
        if self.applicant_school_2 == '/':
            self.applicant_school_2 = ''
        if self.applicant_major_2 == '/':
            self.applicant_major_2 = ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On save, update both timestamps """

        self._created = datetime.datetime.now()
        self._updated = datetime.datetime.now()

        return super(Application, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #end save

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On update, update only _updated timestamps """

        self._updated = datetime.datetime.now()

        return super(Application, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #end update

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
    #end unicode

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'certs_application'
    #end meta
```

Snippet from views.py:

```
if request.POST:
    app_form = ApplicationForm(request.POST)
    app_form.fields['estimated_grad_semester'].widget.choices = build_semester_list('', 12)

    if app_form.is_valid():
        print 'form is valid...'
        app_instance = get_object_or_404(Application, id=app_id)
        fields = {'program': app_form.cleaned_data['program'],
                  'status': app_form.cleaned_data['status'],
                  'applicant_id': application.applicant_id,
                  'applicant_affirmation': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_affirmation'],
                  'applicant_interest_stmt': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_interest_stmt'],
                  'applicant_school': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_school'],
                  'applicant_major': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_major'],
                  'applicant_school_2': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_school_2'],
                  'applicant_major_2': app_form.cleaned_data['applicant_major_2'],
                  'gpa_univ': app_form.cleaned_data['gpa_univ'],
                  'estimated_grad_semester': app_form.cleaned_data['estimated_grad_semester'],
                  '_created_by': app_instance._created_by,
                  '_created': app_instance._created,
                  '_updated_by': user.eid,
                  }
        try:
            application = Application(pk=app_id, **fields)
            application.update()
        except Exception, exception:
            return HttpResponse('Error: ' + str(exception))

        return redirect('application_view', app_id=app_id)

    else:
        print 'app_form is NOT valid'
else:
    # -------------------------------------------
    # render the application using GET
    # -------------------------------------------
    app_form = ApplicationForm(admin=admin_user, instance=application)
    app_form.fields['estimated_grad_semester'].widget.choices = build_semester_list('', 12)
```

Final modifications made that resulted in the needed fix:

views.py

```
if request.POST:
    app_form = ApplicationForm(admin=admin_user, data=request.POST)
```

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, admin, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.admin = admin
    if self.admin:
        self.fields['applicant_interest_stmt'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['applicant_affirmation'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True


def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    cleaned_data = super(ApplicationForm, self).clean()
    if not self.admin:
        applicant_interest_stmt = cleaned_data.get('applicant_interest_stmt')
        applicant_affirmation = cleaned_data.get('applicant_affirmation')
        if not applicant_interest_stmt:
            msg = u'Please provide an interest statement.'
            self._errors["applicant_interest_stmt"] = self.error_class([msg])
        if not applicant_affirmation:
            msg = u'Please check the affirmation checkbox.'
            self._errors["applicant_affirmation"] = self.error_class([msg])
    return cleaned_data
```

**NOTE**: there is still a lingering problem with getting a non-modifiable setting on the applicant_affirmation Boolean field, but I'll fix that separately from this issue.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://chriskief.com/2013/09/28/django-modelform-and-conditionally-disabled-readonly-fields/) addressing your use case. That seems to me like it might be the best solution. Certainly your `clean` method also needs to be adjusted to cover the case when they are disabled. Not sure if this will cause other corner-case problems (like with `update`).

Comment: Thanks @Two-BitAlchemist...this certainly shows promise. I'm having trouble, however, understanding how to use the individual field-level clean methods that the author gives as examples. What calls them? Perhaps an overall clean method? I'm unsure. Thoughts?

Comment: The top few paragraphs in the [form and fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) address the call order. In short, yes, they are called individually by `clean`. `clean_<fieldname>` methods may exist or not, and should either return "cleaned" data for said field or raise a `ValidationError`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm still unable to make this work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to make the admin a golobal to the class

```
class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Application
    fields = ('program', 'status', 'applicant_affirmation', 'applicant_interest_stmt', 'applicant_school', 'applicant_major', 'applicant_school_2', 'applicant_major_2', 'gpa_univ', 'estimated_grad_semester')
    widgets = {
        'applicant_interest_stmt': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}),
        'estimated_grad_semester': Select(),
    }

def __init__(self, admin, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.admin = admin
    if self.admin:
        self.fields['applicant_interest_stmt'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
        self.fields['applicant_affirmation'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'


def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    cleaned_data = super(ApplicationForm, self).clean()
    if not self.admin:
        applicant_interest_stmt = cleaned_data.get('applicant_interest_stmt')
        applicant_affirmation = cleaned_data.get('applicant_affirmation')
        if not applicant_interest_stmt:
            msg = u'Please provide an interest statement.'
            self._errors["applicant_interest_stmt"] = self.error_class([msg])
        if not applicant_affirmation:
            msg = u'Please check the affirmation checkbox.'
            self._errors["applicant_affirmation"] = self.error_class([msg])
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I actually did have that in a previous iteration. I tried it again though, more exactly with what you offer here, but alas...no luck. Form is still not getting past the is_valid check.

Comment: @KeithE How are you inserting the _created_by and _updated_by as they are required fields

Comment: ...I'm passing those directly from my views.py

Comment: @KeithE you might want to do
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

then you can remove your override in the save

Comment: @KeithE Can I have that bit of you view

Comment: I had attempted to use the auto_now_add = True concept a while back when this was first written and encountered problems with it. I'm hesitant to reintroduce it now, as that is not likely the source of my problem. That piece works fine...the .save() and .update() functions work fine when I don't have any overrides in the clean() method.

Comment: @KeithE I know it not the source of your problem. I am using it without a problem. If you send a copy of your view it might help

Comment: @KeithE app_form = ApplicationForm(request.POST) you need to pass admin otherwise it think the request.POST is your admin argument

Comment: You are do to much in your view you should something like.

def sample_form_view(request, enquiry_id):
    enquiry = get_object_or_404(Enquiry, id=enquiry_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EnquiryForm(request.POST, instance=enquiry)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/"))
    else:
        form = EnquiryForm(instance=enquiry)
    return render(request, 'address_book/enquiry_form.html', {
        'list': enquiry.list,
        'new': False,
        'form': form})

Comment: I had tried that early-on with "app_form = ApplicationForm(request.POST, admin=admin_user), but it comes up as a "duplicate argument". How should I pass it?

Comment: @KeithE app_form = ApplicationForm(admin_user, model=request.POST),

Comment: Sorry...that's giving me the error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'

Comment: @KeithE  sorry it was data not model

Comment: ApplicationForm(admin_user, data=request.POST)

Comment: My apologies...I should have realized it was data vs. model as well. It seems to work now! Thank you so much for your help. I'll post an update to the original post with the views.py and forms.py snippets that were modified to make it work. I appreciate your time!